# Blitzstein Page 174, derivation of binomial variance

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

[image]

**This from Blitzstein, page 174. I don't understand the following:

1. What is $E\binom{X}{2}$ [the lines highlighted in blue in the text]? How can one take combinations of random variables, how is it defined?
2. How do we calculate $E\binom{X}{2} = \binom{n}{2} p^2$?
3. What is the intuition of defining our random variable this way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first time seeing this argument for finding $\mathbb{E}X^2$. Nonetheless I will try to answer your doubts.

1. $\mathbb{E} \binom{X}{2}$ is just the expectation of a function acting on $X$. Say
   $$
     f(k) = \binom{k}{2} = \frac{k(k - 1)}{2},
   $$
   and
   $$
     \mathbb{E} \binom{X}{2} = \mathbb{E} f(X) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X(X - 1)}{2} \right].
   $$
2. First, $\binom{X}{2}$ can be understood as after the trial, $X = n$
   which is deterministic, then $\binom{X}{2} = \binom{n}{2}$ is just the number of pair of trials that succeeded. This is what the *italic* words mean. This is the same as pairing up each trial, do the experiment and keep only the pairs that both succeeded, then count the number of such pairs. Following this line of thought, we can define an indicator for every pair of experiment, where each pair have a chance of $p^2$ to succeed due to independence. $\mathbb{E} \binom{X}{2}$ is just the sum of each indicator multiply by its chances of success, which
   $$
     \mathbb{E} \binom{X}{2} = \binom{n}{2} p^2,
   $$
   since each pair having the same success rate $p^2$, and there are a total of $\binom{n}{2}$ of such trials.
3. From the formula
   $$
     \mathbb{E} \binom{X}{2} = \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X(X - 1)}{2} \right],
   $$
   we can generate $\mathbb{E} X^2$. The motivation here is to use a counting argument instead of an algebraic one to derive the variance formula. Sometimes a counting argument is more direct but for this example I would prefer the computaions.

Comment: I understand points 1 and 3, thank you so much. Very grateful.

Sorry, I still don't understand point 2 at all. nC2 counts all possible two-combinations. So, when one says XC2 what is one saying? What does this random variable say? Don't we have to sum across all values of the random variable?

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can understand it as first complete the trials to get a deterministic value of $X$, say $n$, then perform $nC2$. Realistically, view the experiment having two stages, one for $X$ then the seond one which is choosing pairs. Normally to compute the expectation, one need to sum over all occurences with its probability. But here we set an indicator for each pair, which can only take the value $0$ or $1$. By linearity of expectation, it is the sum of the success rate of each pair, which for every pair is just $p^2$.

Comment: And why does nC2 count the number of trials that succeeded. I mean, after n trials, some succeeded, some failed. So, why does nC2 count the number of successful trials?

Comment: For a binomial r.v., $X$ is the number of successful trials, so is $n$.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I have got it. So you are saying, we associate an indicator random variable for each pair of trials. Then we have E(X_1+X_2+X_3 +...NC2 such pairs) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + ....E(X_(NC2)) = p^2(NC2). But then this form of  a random variable only counts those pairs which are both simultaneously successful. What about the cases where only of the two is successful?

Comment: Your summation is correct. I don't fully understand your last one. Do you mean only one of the two is successful? In this case the indicator would be $0$. More formally, we can define the indicator as $I_{jk} = 1$ if $I_j = I_k = 1$ and $0$ otherwise, where $j \neq k$ and $I_j$ is the original indicator from your image.

Comment: All good now. It makes perfect sense, thank you so much! Just that in point 3, I think, you may have made a typo. E(XC2) = E(X(X-1)/2), I think you forgot to put an "E" before the RHS. 

Thank you for everything.

Comment: Yeah, that is a typo. Thank you for point that out, and I have corrected those.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

1. We can think about taking the expectation of combinations of random variables like this: imagine you simulate your set of $n$ iid Bernoulli rvs, resulting in an integer number $k$ of successes. Then it is straightforward to compute ${k \choose 2}$ for this specific $k$.
2. Generalizing the logic above we can write:
   $$
   E{x \choose 2} = \sum_{k=0}^n p(k) {k \choose 2} = \sum_{k=0}^n p^k (1-p)^{n-k} {n \choose k} {k \choose 2} = \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^n p^k (1-p)^{n-k} {n \choose k} (k-1)k = \frac12 n(n-1)p^2
   $$
3. The intuition here is a little complicated and I'm not sure this example computation is really that helpful. Whats going on is that we are computing the expected number of pairs of successful trials. We know algebraically that this is equal to $E[X(X-1)] = E[X^2 - X] = E[X^2] - E[X]$. Since $E[X] = np$ is easy to compute its easy to jump from $E[X^2] - E[X]$ to the variance $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$. I think Blitzstein means this example to highlight how we can use the fact that $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ to compute the variance even if we did not know that the Binomial was a sum of iid rvs.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.